# Is there updated object model for Foursquare API responses (Scala is preferred)?

Tags: foursquare

Is there updated object model for Foursquare API responses ?

The one that they have on Github is 2 years old and differs significantly from what I see in API documentation.

I know you guys (4sq team) switched to Scala. Have (could) you published(publish) set of your case classes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the libraries are maintained by third party developers, so unfortunately some of them have decayed with age. The documentation for what should be returned by each endpoint is available at https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/.

And, if you make a new up-to-date library, feel free to e-mail it to Foursquare, and we can add it to the libraries page!

Comment: Why don't you guys publish case classes from your codebase ? I can even help you with that if necessary.